# Why does my Excel User Form VBA search work with one table column and not another?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a User Form that searches a table column and returns all the values in the row as editable fields on the form.  It works fantastic!  But I wanted to add another column to the search.  I would like to use the last 4 numbers of an 11 digit number so I created another column with a formula that returns the last 4 digits.

I set the variable with:

`RecordRow = Application.Match(CLng(TextBoxSearch.Value), Range("JobSheet[W/O]"), 0)`.
and it works fine.  The column is filled with 6 digit numbers populated by this reference: `=IFERROR(JobSheetData[@[W/O]],"")`.

However, when I change it to this:

`RecordRow = Application.Match(CLng(TextBoxSearch.Value), Range("JobSheet[Ticket Search]"), 0)`
it will not find the row with the search value.

I have a column in the table that uses this reference `=IFERROR(JobSheetData[@[ON1Call Ticket '#]],"")` and then I have the column `Ticket Search` that contains the last 4 digits as mentioned above.

The `W/O` column that is searchable has every line filled with data but 40% of the `Ticket Search` column is blank.  I tried removing values from the `W/O` column to see if that was the issue but it still worked.

Here is all the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim RecordRow As Long
    Dim RecordRange As Range
    Dim sChkBoxResult As String
 
    ' Turn off default error handling so Excel does not display
    ' an error if the record number is not found
    On Error Resume Next
        
    'Find the row in the table that the record is in

**This one works:**
     RecordRow = Application.Match(CLng(TextBoxSearch.Value), Range("JobSheet[W/O]"), 0)
        
**This one doesn't:**
     RecordRow = Application.Match(CLng(TextBoxSearch.Value), Range("JobSheet[Ticket Search]"), 0)
            
    ' Set RecordRange to the first cell in the found record
        Set RecordRange = Range("JobSheet").Cells(1, 1).Offset(RecordRow - 1, 0)

    ' If an erro has occured i.e the record number was not found
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    
            ErrorLabel.Visible = True
            On Error GoTo 0
            Exit Sub
        
        End If
        
    ' Turn default error handling back on (Let Excel handle errors from now on)
       On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' If the code gets to here the record number was found
    ' Hide the error message 'Not Found'
       ErrorLabel.Visible = False
    
   
    ' and populate the form fields with the record's data
        TextBoxNameAddress.Value = RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 3).Value & " - " & RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 2).Value & " " & RecordRange(1, 1).Value
        TextBoxHold.Value = RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 5).Value
        TextBoxDays.Value = RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 7).Value
        CheckBoxLocate.Value = RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 9).Value
        TextBoxCount.Value = RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 11).Value
        TextBoxFirst.Value = RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 13).Value
        TextBoxOveride.Value = RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 14).Value
        CheckBoxBell.Value = RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 15).Value
        CheckBoxGas.Value = RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 16).Value
        CheckBoxHydro.Value = RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 17).Value
        CheckBoxWater.Value = RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 18).Value
        CheckBoxCable.Value = RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 19).Value
        CheckBoxOther1.Value = RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 20).Value
        CheckBoxOther2.Value = RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 21).Value
        CheckBoxOther3.Value = RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 22).Value
       
End Sub
```

UPDATE:

Here is a screenshot of some sample data:
[image: Sample Data]
The data starts in column A

My ultimate goal was to have an if statement that would run either the 6 digit search on the `W/O` column or the 4 digit search on the `ON1Call Ticket #` column based on the length of the string in `TextBoxSearch` Since they are either 4 digit or 6 digit, I thought I would base it on if the value was `>9999` but the `ON1Call Ticket #' column is a text column and not numeric and the search fails.

When the first utility locate arrives the 10 or 11 digit ticket number  is automatically added to the Job Sheet.  As the emails arrive from the various utilities, the ticket number is always used for identification.  I have an automation that extracts the Ticket number and saves the incoming locates as PDF files using the ticket number and some random characters characters as the file name.  I have it set up to split the filename like this: `123456 7890 - jkes.pdf`.  A person now renames the file to indicate what utilities are included in that file and and uses the middle set of 4 numbers in the User Form: [image]
to find the correct record and check the checkbox of the corresponding utility.  I don't want the user to have to type all 11 digits and I was trying to avoid a helper column but I could not figure out how to make the 4 digit search look only at the last 4 digits of the ticket number.

At other times we need to search by the Work Order # which is 6 digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would maybe do something like this:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim RecordRow As Variant '<<< not Long, or throws an error when no match
    Dim vSearch As Long, col, lo As ListObject
    
    Set lo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").ListObjects("JobSheet") 'adjust sheet name
    vSearch = CLng(TextBoxSearch.Value)
    
    For Each col In Array("W/O", "Ticket Search") 'loop over columns to search in
        'no need for On Error Resume Next - test the return value from Match instead
        RecordRow = Application.Match(vSearch, lo.ListColumns(col).DataBodyRange, 0)
        If Not IsError(RecordRow) Then Exit For 'got a hit - stop searching
    Next col
    
    ErrorLabel.Visible = IsError(RecordRow) 'hide/show error label
    If Not IsError(RecordRow) Then LoadRecord lo.ListRows(RecordRow).Range
    
End Sub
```

EDIT: after clarification - different search methods depending on length of input

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim RecordRow As Variant '<<< not Long, or throws an error when no match
    Dim vSearch, col, lo As ListObject
    
    Set lo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").ListObjects("JobSheet") 'adjust sheet name
    
    vSearch = TextBoxSearch.Value
    If Not IsNumeric(vSearch) Then
        MsgBox "Search value must be numeric!"
    End If
    'decide how to search based on length of search input
    Select Case Len(vSearch)
        Case 4
            'call custom function instead of Match
            RecordRow = EndsWithMatch(vSearch, lo.ListColumns("ON1Call Ticket #").DataBodyRange)
        Case 6
            'cast search value to Long before using Match
            RecordRow = Application.Match(CLng(vSearch), lo.ListColumns("W/O").DataBodyRange, 0)
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Search value must either 4 or 6 digits!"
    End Select
   
    ErrorLabel.Visible = IsError(RecordRow) 'hide/show error label
    If Not IsError(RecordRow) Then LoadRecord lo.ListRows(RecordRow).Range
    
End Sub
'search a single-column range of data for an "ends with" match to `vSearch`
Function EndsWithMatch(vSearch, rngSrch As Range)
    Dim i As Long, arr
    arr = rngSrch.Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        If arr(i, 1) Like "*" & vSearch Then
            EndsWithMatch = i
            Exit Function 'done searching
        End If
    Next i
    EndsWithMatch = CVErr(xlErrNA) 'no match: return error value as in Match()
End Function
```

Common to both answers (edit - added some suggestions for saving the edited record):

```vb
Dim editedRow as Range 'holds a reference to the row loaded for editing

'Better as a stand-alone method which you can call from other places...
Sub LoadRecord(sourceRow As Range)
    With sourceRow
        TextBoxNameAddress.Value = .Cells(4).Value & " - " & _
                        .Cells(3).Value & " - " & .Cells(1).Value
        TextBoxHold.Value = .Cells(6).Value
        'etc for other fields
    End With
    Set editedRow = sourceRow 'set a global for the row being edited
    'also enable the "Save" button... 
End Sub

Sub SaveRecord()
    If Not editedRow Is Nothing Then
        With editedRow
            .Cells(6).Value = TextBoxHold.Value
            'etc for the other fields
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "No row is being edited!"
    End If
End Sub
```

It's easier/safer to test the return value from `Match()` than to turn off errors.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Williams, your method is definitely cleaner than what I had previously but it still will not find the row when I am searching the 'Ticket Number' column.  If I add NUMBERVALUE to the formula that creates the 4 digits, it will find it but then my values can be anywhere from 1-4 digits which could lead to duplicates.  This means that the search is only searching numeric values and not text values.  How would I make it find text values as well?

Comment: Might be easier to show some samples of the data you want to search (eg) as a screenshot.  It would be easer not to need helper columns to make this work, and unless you have a huge amount of data, a simple looped search would be fine.  Sample data would be useful here though.

Comment: If you could look at the search value entered and use that to determine which column to search, describing exactly what steps would be involved would also help.  Forget the helper columns for now.

Comment: I have updated the question to include sample data.  There is only ever expected to be at most 200-300 rows in the sheet. so it is not a huge dataset.

Comment: Perhaps the solution lies in checking if the content of the cells ends in the value entered into the search box.

Comment: See the update I just posted

Comment: My only slight concern might be that the last 4 digits of the ticket # might not be unique?  What if >1 match exists?

Comment: You solution works perfectly.   The W/O column should never have duplicate.   There is a possibility, albeit remote, that there is a duplicate final 4 digits of the locate number.  Perhaps adding a message box that lists the full Ticket Numbers and allows you to select the one you want. Any thought on how we could accomplish that?

Comment: You'd need a userform for the user to make that selection...   A bit more complex than the "single match" scenario.

Comment: It is a remote chance with the number or records we have.  After 60 days they will have been either removed or assigned a new ticket number.  I don't see the point of wasting time on it unless it becomes an issue.  Thanks so much Tim!  Your help has been invaluable!

Comment: How would I reference the cells in the opposite direction to save modified values back to the row?  I have tried to use this same process but reversing the LoadRecord Sub but can't get anything to work.  Should I post this as new question?

Comment: Declare a Global variable in your form module `Dim rwSource As Range` and set it when the search finds a match - create a `SaveRecord` sub which uses the stored range for the update, just reversing the process from `LoadRecord` : eg  `TextBoxHold.Value = .Cells(6).Value` becomes `rwSource.Cells(6).Value = TextBoxHold.Value`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244032/discussion-between-drybsmt-and-tim-williams).

Comment: If you have a follow-on question then please create a new post.

Comment: Nope, I just had one question about implementing the above but I figured it out.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Well Tim, I did not figure it out.  Sorry to bother you.  I know you said start a new post but I just can't figure out what to set the Global variable to:  Set rwSource = ?  I thought I had the answer but it ended up not working.

Comment: Some suggestions in the edit at the bottom of my answer.